# dropzone.js is not displaying images inside a container, rather it is displaying one by one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

why my dropzone implementation images goes to next line,i want to display it inline block as per official demo.

here is my basic configuration in laravel

```
                  <div class="form-group">
                           <div>
                              <div class="col-md-12">
                                     {!! Form::open([ 'url' => ['/contactuspagebanner'], 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'contactUsPageBanner' ]) !!}
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                         </div>
```

my resulting image display is like this,
[the image appear like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWyW0.png)

my question is? how to display this images while drop, inside a container rather than one by one. as seen in the dropzone example,other functionality i can take care of. [what css and js should i include].
   i wanted to achieve result like this..
  [i wanted to achieve result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owO7r.png)

--please help me

Comment: iam still waiting for an answer

Comment: iam still waiting for an answer

Comment: din't find any answer...still waiting..

Comment: iam still looking for an answer